# How to determine the necessary functions of a delegate?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-protocols

How do I know which functions need to be implemented by a class to conform to a protocol?

E.g. `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate` requires `appInviteDialog: didCompleteWithResults` and `appInviteDialog:didFailWithError:`.

Xcode only gives an error without specifying these functions:

> Type 'InviteFriendsController' does not conform to protocol
>   'FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate'

I found the functions in `FBSDKAppInviteContent.h` and they are surely mentioned in the FB docs. But is there an easier way to find the functions?

Comment: You need to add `@interface InviteFriendsController : UIViewController<FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate>`, then press cmd+click on `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate` it will have defined `required` and `optional` protocol functions, the one which are marked as `required` you need to implement those functions.

Comment: Add to where? I'm writing in Swift btw.

Comment: I think [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32575026/790842) will help you..

Comment: Thanks, actually it's alt+click on `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate` to open the info view and then click on `FBSDKAppInviteContent.h` to see the protocol. That's what I did. But I wondered if there was another way to find the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is indeed an easier way to find the missing functions! You just need to click on the Arrow next to the error in the Issue Navigator and expand it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you hold command and press click the protocol name (in your case `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`), the navigator will bring you to the protocol declaration where you can see all the required methods and properties.